# Querying float to filter a Pandas Dataframe get TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that has several columns that have dtype of float.

```
temp = df.query("temp" > 10.00, inplace = True)
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'
```

Additionally finding ideas by using `pd.to_numeric()` option still throws this error.

```
df.temp = pd.to_numeric(df.temp,  errors='coerce')
```

Comment: `"temp" > 10.00` literally attempts to compare a `str`ing `"temp"` and a `float`ing-point number `10.00`. What's not clear here? Note that `"temp"` and `df.temp` are different things.

Comment: `df.query('temp>10')`? `.query` takes `str` only as `expr`'s value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

query() method takes string expression only.

Try this:

```
    df.query('temp > 10', inplace = True)
```

Comment: Thanks, totally over looked that option.